# Use of virtio on QEMU without KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virtio

I want to write a simple driver for use inside a `QEMU` virtual machine, which will be communicating with the host through a respective backend special virtual device.

The said driver and backend device will be using the `VirtIO` functionality to work. This driver is the objective of a university exercise, which suggests that the `QEMU` must work with `KVM`, on a processor with virtualization technology.

However I have a quite old machine, the CPU of which has no such utility. Putting performance aside, I was wondering, will I be able to use the VirtIO functionality or is it something that can only be used alongside `KVM`?

The documentation found on the internet about VirtIO is virtually non existent, that is the reason I hope someone here knows something.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help, but note that you might be able to buy a raspberry pi zero for about $5US and [some people](http://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/) have managed to run qemu/kvm on a pi (pi 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtio is an API for virtual IO that implements network and block driver logic, and it can be implemented with QEMU and no KVM.  See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-libvirt/) for a thorough overview of libvirt, including examples without using KVM.